# How can I run parSequenceUnordered of Monix, and handle the results of each task?

Tags: scala, monix, sttp

I am currently working on implementing client-side http requests to an API, and decided to explore sttp & monix for this task. As I am  new to Monix, I am still not sure how to run tasks and retrieve their results. My objective is to have a sequence of http request results, which I can call in parallel -> parse -> load.

Below is a snippet of what I have tried so far:

```
import sttp.client._
import sttp.client.asynchttpclient.monix._
import monix.eval.Task

object SO extends App {

  val postTask = AsyncHttpClientMonixBackend().flatMap { implicit backend =>
    val r1 = basicRequest.get(uri"https://hello.world.io/v1/bla")
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .response(asString)
      .body()
      .send()

    val tasks = Seq(r1).map(i => Task(i))
    Task.parSequenceUnordered(tasks).guarantee(backend.close())
  }
  
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

  postTask.runToFuture.foreach(println) // prints: List(Task.FlatMap$2052527361)
}
```

My confusion is rather a simple one (I am guessing). How can I run the `Task.parSequenceUnordered` that I have created, and handle (parse the http results) the Tasks within the sequence?

Nice to have: out of curiosity, is it possible to naively introduce rate-limiting/throttling when processing the Task sequence of requests? I am not really looking for building something sophisticated. It could be as simple as spacing out batches of requests. Wondering if Monix has a helper for that already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [Oleg Pyzhcov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2758343/oleg-pyzhcov) and the [monix gitter community](https://gitter.im/monix/monix) for helping me figure this one out.

Quoting Oleg here:

> Since you're using backend with monix support already, the type of r1
> is `Task[Response[Either[String,String]]]`. So when you're doing
> `Seq(r1).map(i => Task(i))`, you make it a sequence of tasks that don't
> do anything except give you other tasks that give you result (the type
> would be `Seq[Task[Task[Response[...]]]]`). Your code then parallelizes
> the outer layer, tasks-that-give-tasks, and you get the tasks that you
> started with as the result. You only need to process a Seq(r1) for it
> to run requests in parallel.
>
> If you're using Intellij, you can press `Alt + =` to see the type of
> selection - it helps if you can't tell the type from the code alone
> (but it gets better with experience).
>
> As for rate-limiting, we have parSequenceN that lets you set a limit
> to parallelism. Note that unordered only means that you get slight
> performance advantage at the cost of results being in random order in
> the output, they are executed non-deterministically anyway.

I ended up with a (simplified) implementation that looks something like this:

```
import sttp.client._
import sttp.client.asynchttpclient.monix._
import monix.eval.Task

object SO extends App {

  val postTask = AsyncHttpClientMonixBackend().flatMap { implicit backend =>
    val r1 = basicRequest.get(uri"https://hello.world.io/v1/bla")
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .response(asString)
      .body()
      .send()

    val items = Seq(r1.map(x => x.body))
    Task.parSequenceN(1)(items).guarantee(backend.close())
  }
  
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global

   postTask.runToFuture.foreach(println)
}
```